# When is "Northern fall"?

Tags: meaning, australian-english

One of my favorite Australian YouTubers keeps saying "Northern" to mean one of "early" or "late", and I don't know which. For example:

> The new Pokémon DLC is coming Northern fall.

When is it coming?!?

Comment: Are you sure you aren't mishearing them? Do you have a link to the video?

Comment: Here's a link to a video where they use these words, at around 13:34: https://youtu.be/G_G_PblQnx8?t=814

Comment: Actually, I just had a brainwave, is it possible he means "Northern hemisphere fall"? To distinguish that he means September-December for his Australian viewers that might consider March-June to be "fall"?

Comment: You beat me to it!

Comment: Haha, I was convinced it must be some kind of idiom. But nope, just upside-down-land things! Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Australia is in the southern hemisphere; when it is fall in the northern hemisphere, it is spring in Australia, and vice versa. "Northern fall" means the time when it is fall in the *northern* hemisphere; presumably the YouTuber is disambiguating because, while he is Australian, much of his audience likely lives in the northern hemisphere (say, the US and UK).

Comment: A curious way to denote *austral spring*.

Comment: That's why they named it "Southia".